# Updating an Object in a multistep form deletes priors entries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, forms, react-props

This is the set up:

In App.js i have routes for each step. i have a main object in which im updating values as the steps progress using props.

Here is my object:

```js
const [postData, setPostData2] = useState({

    'meta': {
      "originally_created": todaysDate,
      "user_agent": navigator.userAgent,
      "ip_address": ip,
      "tcpa_compliant": true,
      "tcpa_consent_text": "By clicking Get My Free Quote below, I am agreeing to receive text messages from InsurTech Groups and business partners. I provide my signature expressly consenting to recurring contact from InsurTech Groups  or its business partners at the number I provided regarding products or services via live, automated or prerecorded telephone call, text message, or email. I understand that my telephone company may impose charges on me for these contacts, and I am not required to enter into this agreement as a condition of purchasing property, goods, or services. I understand that I can revoke this consent at any time. Terms & conditions & Privacy policy apply.",
      "landing_page_url": ""

    },

    "contact": {
      "first_name": "",
      "last_name": "",
      "email": "",
      "phone": "",
      "address": "",
      "city": "",
      "state": "",
      "zip_code": "",
      "ip_address": ip,
    },

    "data": {
      "drivers": [
        {
          "first_name": "",
          "last_name": "",
          "birth_date": "",
          "gender": "",
        },
        {
          "first_name": "",
          "last_name": "",
          "birth_date": "",
          "gender": "",
        }
      ],

      "vehicles": [{
        "year": "",
        "make": "",
        "model": "",
      },
      {
        "year": "",
        "make": "",
        "model": "",
      }
      ],

      "requested_policy": {
        "coverage_type": "",
      },
      "current_policy": {
        "insurance_company": "",
      }
    }
  });
```

Here is some logic so i can update the object with props:

```js
 useEffect(() => {

    const stringifiedData = sessionStorage.getItem('main-form-data')

    if (stringifiedData) {
      const jsonData = JSON.parse(stringifiedData);
      setPostData(jsonData);
    }

  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {

    sessionStorage.setItem('main-form-data', JSON.stringify(postData));

  }, [JSON.stringify(postData)]);


  const setPostData = (obj) => {
    console.log('in app state', obj);
    setPostData2(obj)
  }

  const setPostDataForPage = (data) => {
    setPostData({ ...postData, ...data });
  }
```

and this is how im passing it into each route:

```js
  <Route
          path="/car-year"
          element={<CarYear setPostData={setPostDataForPage} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/car-make"
          element={<CarMake setPostData={setPostDataForPage} />}
        />

        <Route
          path="/car-model"
          element={<CarModel setPostData={setPostDataForPage} />}
        />
```

So here is the issue:

As i updated Car Year, Car Make & Car Model it updates in the console log as it supposed to but everytime it console log it completely overwrites the prior object.

Example:

YEAR STEP:

```js
....rest of console log from object
vehicels: year: 1991
```

MAKE STEP:

```js
....rest of console log from object
vehicels: make: Honda
```

as you can see it just over writes the year and replaces it with just the make

Here is how im updating in each step:

CAR YEAR PROPS UPDATE:

```js
 props.setPostData({
      vehicles: 
        {
          year: year,
        }
      
    })
```

CAR MAKE PROPS UPDATE:

```js
props.setPostData({
      vehicles: [
        {
          make: make,
        }
      ]
    })
```

Why does it do this and how can i fix it?

Here is a ***bonus** question lol, if i have two vehicles how can i make sure that when the person enters a second vehicle it doenst overwrite the first vehicle data!

I know this one is super long and thank you in advance!!!! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're spreading the original state in the setter. React won't mutate the state synchronously, so you end calling all 3 setters on the original state.

To use the actual state, pass a callback to the state setter with the previous state as the parameter.

```
const setPostDataForPage = (data) => {
  setPostData(prevData => { ...prevData, ...data });
}
```